# Failed to create query for method public abstract

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

> Simple I want test my application to connect with database to insert
> some record statically.
> it properly work or not.but it throws this type of error that i
> mentioned below;
> I donot know where i make mistake,I define everything properly

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'turistRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.main.ToursTravels.model.Turist com.main.ToursTravels.repo.TuristRepo.findByName(java.lang.String)! No property name found for type Turist!
```

> turistrepo.java

```
 package com.main.ToursTravels.repo;
    
    import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    
    import com.main.ToursTravels.model.Turist;
    
    @Repository
    public interface TuristRepo extends CrudRepository<Turist, Long> {
        Turist findByName(String turistname);
    
    }
```

> vechiletyperepo.java

```
package com.main.ToursTravels.repo;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.main.ToursTravels.model.Turist;
import com.main.ToursTravels.model.VechileType;
@Repository
public interface VechileTypeRepo extends CrudRepository<VechileType, Long> {
    List<VechileType> findByTurist(Turist turist , Sort sort);

}
```

> mainclasss.java

```
package com.main.ToursTravels;


import java.time.LocalDate;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.main.ToursTravels.model.Turist;
import com.main.ToursTravels.model.VechileKind;
import com.main.ToursTravels.model.VechileType;
import com.main.ToursTravels.repo.TuristRepo;
import com.main.ToursTravels.repo.VechileTypeRepo;


@SpringBootApplication
public class ToursTravelsApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ToursTravelsApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Autowired
    TuristRepo trp;
    @Autowired
    VechileTypeRepo vtrp;
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Turist trs = new Turist();
        trs.setTuristname("NewsWels");
        trs.setTravelkm(100);
        trs.setTraveldate(LocalDate.of(2020, 20, 11));
        trs.setDrivername("prabhka5r");
        VechileType vtp= new VechileType();
        vtp.setVechilekind(VechileKind.SEDAN);
        vtp.setRateperkm(6);
        vtp.setMinprice(2530.00);
        trs.setVechileno("GJ05K2619");
        trs.setTotalamount(15186.00);
        trs.setBookingstatus(true);
        
        trs.setVechiletype(vtp);
        vtp.setTurist(trs);
        
        trp.save(trs);
        
    }

}
```

> turist.java

```
package com.main.ToursTravels.model;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDate;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;



import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Table(name="turist")
@Data
public class Turist {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="truist_id")
    private Long truistid;
    @Column(name="turistname")
    private String turistname;
    @Column(name="travel_km")
    private int travelkm;
    @Column(name="travel_date")
    private LocalDate traveldate;
    @Column(name="drivername")
    private String drivername;
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="booking_id")
    private VechileType vechiletype;
    @Column(name="vechileno")
    private String vechileno;
    @Column(name="total_amount")
    private Double totalamount;
    @Column(name="BOOKING_status")
    private boolean bookingstatus;
    
    public Turist(){}

    public Turist(String turistname, int travelkm, LocalDate traveldate, String drivername, VechileType vechiletype,
            String vechileno, Double totalamount, boolean bookingstatus) {
        super();
        this.turistname = turistname;
        this.travelkm = travelkm;
        this.traveldate = traveldate;
        this.drivername = drivername;
        this.vechiletype = vechiletype;
        this.vechileno = vechileno;
        this.totalamount = totalamount;
        this.bookingstatus = bookingstatus;
    }
     
    


}
```

> VechileType.java

```
package com.main.ToursTravels.model;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;



import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Table(name="vechiletype")
@Data
public class VechileType {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="booking_id")
    private Long  bookingid;
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="vechiletype")
    private Turist turist;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="vechilekind")
    private VechileKind vechilekind;
    @Column(name="rate_per_km")
    private int rateperkm;
    @Column(name="miniprice")
    private Double minprice;
    
    public VechileType(){}

    public VechileType(Turist turist, VechileKind vechilekind, int rateperkm, Double minprice) {
        this.turist = turist;
        this.vechilekind = vechilekind;
        this.rateperkm = rateperkm;
        this.minprice = minprice;
    }
    
    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Repository method references a `name` field for your `Turist` class, but none exists. You have `turistname` available to query.

So your method name should be this:

```
Turist findByTuristname(String turistname);
```